# how can i make a value from database by accessing from datareader as a selected item in dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, editing, datareader

```
                ddlIType.DataSource = bl.getitype(dbo);
                ddlIType.DataTextField = "IndustryType";
                ddlIType.DataValueField = "IndustryId";
                ddlIType.DataBind();
                ddlIType.Items.FindByValue(ddlIType.DataValueField).Selected = true;

 public string getitype(DataObject bo)
        {
            return db.industrytype(bo);
        }

  public void getProfil(DataObject bo)
        {

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM JobSeeker_ProfileSnapShot where JobSeekerId ='" + bo.JobSeekerId + "'", conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

            //string i = (string )reader["FirstName"];
            //return reader;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                fn = (string)reader["FirstName"];
                lname = (string)reader["LastName"];
                sname = (string)reader["SurName"];
                rhline = (string)reader["ResumeHeadline"];
                pl = (string)reader["PreferedLocation"];
                asal = (decimal)reader["AnnualSalary"];
                itype = (string)reader["IndustryType"];
                fa = (string)reader["FunctionalAreaName"];
                rn = (string)reader["RoleName"];
                pa = (string)reader["PermanentAddress"];
                dob = (DateTime)reader["DateOfBirth"];
                g = (bool)reader["Gender"];
                cnt = (string)reader["Country"];
                st = (string)reader["State"];
                ct = (string)reader["City"];
                pc = (string)reader["Pincode"];
                mt = (string)reader["Maritalstatus"];

            }
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
---------------------------------------

 public string industrytype(DataObject bo)
        {

            getProfil(bo);
            return itype;
        }
```

Comment: can you rephrase your question? a headline and a chunk of code doesn't exactly explain your specific problem...

Comment: actually i have retrieved one record from database.. that record was inserted based on some textboxes and selected values in dropdown.. now my requirement is to show all that values automatically in the controls when we open that form in editable mode by fetching from database... here i am using datareader concept to perform this.. through that datareader i am able to show the values of text boxes.. but im unable to show the value of dropdownlist as the selected value....